# life decrease on collision

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, collision

I am making a little game using HTML5 Canvas and javascript. I am so far that I have a kite moving some sort of power up on collision and an obstacle on collision.

Now I'm at the point I want to add lives and when you hit an obstacle your life will decrease 1.

I tried some stuff and when you hit an obstacle the life decreases but it decreases constantly and the player image gets removed instead of the obstacle image.

here is the life thing you can check all the code there.

http://nickzijlstra.com/kite

Here the code I think is the most important for the problem.

```
 function  hitObject(player, obj){
var a = (obj.x - player.x),
b = (obj.y - player.y),
c = Math.sqrt(a*a + b*b),
r0 = player.image.width/2,
r1 = obj.image.width/2;

 if (c < r0+r1) { 
player.drawable = false;
lifes -=1;


window.location.reload(true);       
  }
 }
```

If someone sees the problem or knows the solution I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Please post the relevant code *here*. Find the key sections of your code related to the problem, and post just that, not the whole code.

Comment: your game is cool, but it should move faster.  its way too easy to get those wings

Comment: Thank you, it is long from finished haha !

Comment: People are not going to dig through your website to review your code.  Place the relevant code here (i.e. the portion of the code where that through your debugging efforts would seem to be where the problem resides.

Comment: already added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the player disappears is because of this line in the `hitObject` function:

```
player.drawable = false;
```

This will cause the player to not be drawn because of this condition in your drawing function:

```
if (player.drawable == true) {
    context.drawImage(player.image, player.x, player.y, player.image.width, player.image.height);
}
```

I presume you actually want to move the `obj` back to a random spot on the top of the screen if the player gets hit. It doesn't do this at the moment, which is why the lives go down rapidly: the object hits the player, it removes a life, and then the next frame it hits the player again (even though the player isn't visible).

What you might want is something like:

```
...
if (c < r0+r1) { 
    lifes -=1;

    // Respawn the object.
    obj.y = -50;
    obj.x = Math.random() * canvas.width;
...
```

Comment: Thank you that is really awesome !!! also I added that when life <=0 the game restarts!

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, I'd say that you should replace the

```
player.drawable = false;
```

with

```
obj.drawable = false;
```

and wrap the whole collision detection inside of an if obj.drawable=true so that removed obstacles won't collide with the kite.

Comment: Yeah already tried that but doesn't work, thanks for the reply though!